# Default value for callback possible in C?

Tags: c, callback

I have a problem, code is better than words.

```c
static void message_cb(int friend_number, char const *message) {
    // ...

    // I need to access instance (from `init`) here.

    // I can't modify the parameters of message_cb unfortunately...


    // ...
} 

// There will be a lots of different `instance`,
// so I can't really use a global variable...
static void init(Chat *instance)
{
    // ...

    callback_message(message_cb);

    // ...
}
```

In short I need to do something like this, but in C:
( like generating a function depending on the `instance` parameters )

```
static void init(Chat *instance)
{
    // ...

    callback_message(void (int friend_number, char const *message) {
        // Here I can access `instance`
    });

    // ...
}
```

Sorry for my short and probably bad english, it's not my native language...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, your question is still unclear.

Comment: does this needs to be executed in a multi threaded context?

Comment: @Ackdari probably in futur, yes

Comment: Given you have to consider a multithreaded environment, cannot change the parameters of your callback, and you have to modify one among many instances within the callback, I cannot think of an idiomatic way to solve this. But if you can relax the need to modify the instance in the callback, to be able to modify it in a function that wraps the callback, then I see a solution

Comment: how does `callback_message` behave? Does it may return before `message_cb` is called or does it only return after `message_cb` has finished?

Comment: and could you alter how `callback_message` works?

Comment: My post has been modified to show concept of thread safety using a lock around a section of code to prevent access if lock is not available at time of call.  This only has to be used in a non-re-entrant function.  (i.e. one that uses for example global resources.)

Answer (score 0):

Given you cannot *modify the parameters of message* *cb* *unfortunately* one way to initialize callback with settable value is to create an `extern` scoped variable, perhaps in a `.h` file providing visibility to any `.c` file that needs its current value or address (depending on how *instance* is defined):

.h file

```
//declare project global here
extern <type><name>;
```

file1.c

```
//define project global here
<type><name> = somevalue;
```

***Note:*** preceding idea was proposed before OP specified multi-threaded environment was probable in response to comments under originally posted question.

***In response to comment about threading...***

If any kind of *global* object (message, value, some other object) is to be used in a multi-threaded environment, then it needs to be protected in such a way as to control when its value can be accessed and modified by creating them for example in one of the two following ways:

- use lock structure (eg mutex) to protect the shared variable using a  *critical section*.
- use atomic operations to access the object, the new C standard, C11 supports this construct.

...or using them in such a way as to surround them with *critical sections* of protected code, such as might be done using a lock.

There are many tutorials on this topic, eg. [this one](https://cs.gmu.edu/~setia/cs475/slides/lecture5.pdf).

Here is a quick and dirty example of the concept of using thread safety via using a lock:

```
// Your function modified with pseudo code for concept illustration

//static void init(Chat *instance)
static bool init(Chat *instance)
{
    bool status = FALSE;
    struct ts_lock lock = {0};
    get_lock(&lock);

    if(lock.granted)
    {
        //populate message from instance here
        // <some code to populate 'message'>
        callback_message(void (int friend_number, char const *message) {
        // Here I can access `instance`

        status = TRUE;
        release_lock(lock);
    }

    return status;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I cannot do this because, the function init will be called a lots of times with different `Chat *` each times, and the callback_message, will be called at any moment or not

Comment: @Ogromny - Are you familiar with _thread safe techniques_? (You had not mentioned this criteria in original post, btw) See edits to post that may help...